# Mysql: remove seconds from epoch time

Tags: mysql, epoch

Im using this method to convert it to a human readable format.

```
select from_unixtime(floor(1389422614485/1000));
```

Output: 2014-01-11 01:43:34

At the same time can I remove seconds from it?
E.g. 2014-01-11 01:43

Comment: use mysql DATE_FORMAT()

Comment: Could you show me an example?

Comment: Am I missing something? But I dont think in your example 34 is representing millisecond. It is rather second

Comment: Sorry It's seconds. thanks for the comment  @Rahul Tripathi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use MySQL `DATE_FORMAT`

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(floor(1389422614485/1000)),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
```